# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (50,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, conv-neural-network

This is my code for cnn model I use flow_from_directory() here I don't know the solution for this error.

If the solution is I have to use One-Hot Encoding to convert the labels into a set of 50 numbers to input into the neural network. Can u explain to me how to use it in my code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,3,3, input_shape = (64,64,3), activation = "sigmoid"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(output_dim = 512, activation="sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=50, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Datasets/300_train',
                                                 target_size=(64,64),
                                                 batch_size = 32,
                                                 class_mode='categorical')

testing_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Datasets/300_test',
                                               target_size=(64,64),
                                               batch_size = 32,
                                               class_mode='categorical')

from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

model.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch=250,
                    epochs=10,validation_data=testing_set,
                    validation_steps=50)
```

This is my error report :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fcc5eb74d290> in <module>
      6                     epochs=10,
      7                     validation_data=testing_set,
----> 8                     validation_steps=50)
 .....
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (50,)
```

Comment: Can you please explain a little more about the data? Specifically the number of classes? I think the train data gen was able to find only one class when looking at directory but the output layer has 50. Modifying final dense layer to 1 should help but that wont make the classifier work.

Comment: the number of the class is 50, train data is 250 in total and 5 images each class. my test data is 50 and 1 image each class

Comment: I have a follow up question, Do you have your test data in 50 different folders with one image in each folder? The stack trace looks like you are having them all in a single folder which makes the model think that there is only one class. Please let me know.

Comment: I put all test images in 50 different folders each folder has 1 image file. and I put all 50 folders in `Datasets/300_test` folder

Comment: Likewise, for my training data, I have saved all my training data into 50 different folders according to the class of each image. And I put all 50 folders in `Datasets/300_train/`

Comment: I get my answer. the problem was in loss function: I can't use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution of my problem is :
change the loss function from `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`
to `categorical_crossentropy`

you can find out more on : [sparse_categorical_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy)
and [categorical_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy)